Unity - Shader Graph & Sorting group Error
I have a question about Unity's Sorting group and Shader Graph.
[interactive 2D water] (https://youtu.be/TbGEKpdsmCI?si=79lD21CmRytbruJF)
I created interactive water after watching this video and applied it to my project.
The problem is the sort order of the water and players.
The player consists of several skinned mesh renderers, so the parent object was sorted in Entity order through a sorting group.
Likewise, the sorting order of the watermesh was set to foreground, which is a higher order than Entity, through sorting group.
I want the water to be in front of the player,
We want the player to be positioned behind the water and see some distortion, but only a portion of it is obscured, as shown in the image.
my current situation
my goal - Player behind transparent water
ps) I watched the YouTube video and followed it as best as I could,
Without knowing why The URP camera settings seem strange.
Could this be the problem?
I tried modifying the render queue and z-coordinates, but in the end I couldn't get the desired solution.

Have you tried working with layers?
